# Systemd service executing a script with error handling

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, systemd, service

I have the following issue:
I created a systemd service which executes a script. This script contains several commands including psql commands which queries a database and stores the outcome into variables which are used later...

How can I notify that a query/command is successfully executed in the script by the systemd service file? For example that it checks on return code's, is this a possibility in systemd?
And if this notified can I redirect those errors to specific folders?

I already used the:
SuccessExitStatus=0

But it looks like this doesn't cover my issue.

Tnx in advance,
Cheers.

Comment: systemd only gets the return code of the script itself, not of the commands executed inside it. You could add `set -e` to the start of your script to have it error out as soon as a command fails.

Comment: You can use systemd sockets for interconnecting different applications. So just create a socket unit file for each/all wanted case/s and let handle these cases by these socket unit file/s, activated by your script. https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html

Comment: Tnx all for your reply